# Position a rotated span right

Tags: html, css

I want to create div in which there should be a text like this:

[image]

But I'm not able to position the text right. Since I use `transform: rotate(-90deg);`, I'm completly confused about `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.

My main question is about why the text breaks sometimes, why there are things like `right: -32px;` and is there a good way to keep all responsive (various text length, various length of the re
d block). I've added a screen shot to show in which context I would like to use it:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-block" id="block2" style="height: 90%; left: 120px;">
   <div>
      <span>The Cup of tea</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart-block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #ef0707;
}

.chart-block > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.chart-block > div > span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want

CSS (only the span, the rest remains the same)

```
.chart-block > div > span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3x9Qv/6/)

Notice that the only fixed value is the width of the span. The rest are 0 values (that keep invariant) and percentage values (that should make it fully responsive). About the width, the only requisite is that it is high enough for the text not to be clipped, so it should be easy to find a good value.

Comment: Glad that it helped. (You are fast answering !)

Answer (score 1):

[I would do it something like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/3x9Qv/1/) I rotate the whole block, instead of just the text. That way you can position the text in a more normal fashion.

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-block" id="block2">
    <span>The Cup of tea</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart-block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: #ef0707;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.chart-block span {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why the site is now so high? http://jsfiddle.net/wumm/3x9Qv/3/ I've just added `bottom: 0px;`

Comment: Because you put the div at the bottom, and then rotated it, so half its width (which turns into its height) ends up below the fold.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a position relative on the parent of the text, you could use position absolute on the actual text to position it bottom of the parent, I don't really like using position absolute but this would suit your code.

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-block" id="block2" style="height: 90%; left: 120px;">
    <div>
        <span>The Cup of tea</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart-block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ef0707;
    transition: height ease 1s;
}

.chart-block > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.chart-block > div > span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    left:0;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x9Qv/2/)

However what Watson suggested is also good, but I was thinking of browser compatibility in order to keep the width of your bar as you wanted it.

Comment: At that point I was already, but can you explain me why the text breaks? And why get parts invisible if I change the text?

Comment: Okay I could avoid text breaking by adding `width: 60px;` but the whole thng needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it just there on the page - or frozen in place too?

We have a "Feedback" link that we show in the footer for smaller screens, and on the top right for larger screens: http://jsfiddle.net/wHL7g/

The HTML:

```
<div class="feedbackRequest">
    <a href="/feedback" data-role="none">Feedback</a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.feedbackRequest {
  color: #05afba;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.feedbackRequest a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #05afba;
  color: #05afba;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 70px;
}
.feedbackRequest a:hover {
  border: solid 1px #025257;
  color: #025257;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  .feedbackRequest {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: -32px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .feedbackRequest a {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I don't want to freeze it. It should be very responsive. I've updated my question to clearify this.